# Is it possible to create 2 Azure functions under same solution which are triggered based on service bus queue and both queues are different?

Tags: .net, azure, function

How can I create two azure functions in C# under single solution where each functionApp reads messages from two different queues respectively?
I am unable to specify %queueName% for both functions at same time in localhost json file.

```
[FunctionName("FuncA")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%queueName%", Connection = "sb_connection_string")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
}
```

and

```
[FunctionName("FuncB")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%failedQueueName%", Connection = "sb_connection_string")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
}
```

local setting json file :

```
"queueName" : "queueA",
"%failedQueueName%":"queueB"
```

How to read messages from queueB in funcB?

Error: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%failedQueueName%' does not resolve to a value.`

Comment: can you elaborate on why you're unable to specify another `%queueName%` at the same time in localhost json file? are you getting an error?

Comment: @BrettCaswell, My func A would read from queueA and func2 would read messages from queueB. So funcA is able to read messages from queueA after reading config file value of %queueName% but how should i pass different queue name that is "queueB" for funcB to read from?

Comment: well.. the error indicates a resolving issue.  in your snippet, you have `"%failedQueueName%":"queueB"`, but that should be without `%` when defined in that file. I can't determine if that was your only issue here though. as I presume you're missing (or wish to know how to use) `function.json` and binding here (following the folder structure convention).  you probably should not be resolving with `%` at all, but relate these parameters through bindings.

Comment: If my answer helps, can you [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1SjJ.png) to end this question? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you want to do is definitely possible.

Then I need to explain to you the meaning of the percent sign. In your binding or trigger, in addition to Connection being parsed as an environment variable by default, you need to use a form like `%key%` to specify the value from the environment variable in other locations. Once you mark this way, the function host will try to find the environment variable whose key name is 'key' in the environment variable and replace `%key%` with the value of the corresponding key.

So, the format on your side your be like these:

In trigger or binding, use:

`[ServiceBusTrigger("%queueName%", Connection = "sb_connection_string")]`

`[ServiceBusTrigger("%failedQueueName%", Connection = "sb_connection_string")]`

And set the 'queuename' and 'failedQueueName' in local.settings.json(On azure, you need to set it in the configuration settings.). Like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "queueName": "xxx",
    "failedQueueName": "xxx",
    "sb_connection_string": "xxx"
  }
}
```

And this is the official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings

Comment: Perfect!!, Thanks for the explanation and solution. It works charmingly!! @Bowman Zhu

Comment: For Deadletter queue triggered function will the above syntax work as below:

 [FunctionName("funcC")]
        [return: ServiceBus("failedQueueName", Connection = "sb_connection_string")]
        public static Message Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%queueName%/$DeadLetterQueue", Connection = "sb_connection_string", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)